# Why authorised header is not pass through redirect?

Tags: node.js, express, server-side

I try to pass header through redirect. For some reason i don't get any value in the response header in the redirect path. 
I try to pass header of token through one route to another route via Express package, and then send it to GET response as a result of the answer. On the client side i should get the token and save it.

i got the path "/users/login" that use JWT to generate token and then save it in the header. After that use redirect to "/flights/" and i try to get access to the header but the header "token" is not exist. In the login route the header is exist.

here is the code of "/users/login" route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs')

const user={}

const vt =(req,res,next)=>{

    if(req.headers.token)
        jwt.verify(req.headers.token,"havhav",(err,decoded)=>{
            if(err) res.status(403).send(err)
            else{
                next()
            }
        })
    else{
            bcryptjs.compare(req.body.pass,user.pass,(err,result)=>{
                if(err) throw err
                if(result){
                    jwt.sign({
                        username:user.username
                    }, 'havhav', (err, token) => {
                        if (err) throw err
                        res.header('token', token) 
                        next()
                    })

                }
                else
                    res.status(403).send("unauthorized")
            })

    }

}
router.post('/login',vt,(req,res)=>{

    res.redirect(307,'/flights')
})
module.exports = router
```

here is the code of "/flights/" route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post("/",(req,res)=>{

    res.send("welcome to flights")
})

module.exports = router
```

here is the client side

```
try{
    let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/login',
    {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"username":"idan","pass":"123456"}) 
      }
    )
    console.log(data);
    }
    catch(err) {console.log(err);}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just paste this code in a separate file say vt.js and export it.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs')

const user={}

const vt =(req,res,next)=>{

    if(req.headers.token)
        jwt.verify(req.headers.token,"havhav",(err,decoded)=>{
            if(err) res.status(403).send(err)
            else{
                next()
            }
        })
    else{
            bcryptjs.compare(req.body.pass,user.pass,(err,result)=>{
                if(err) throw err
                if(result){
                    jwt.sign({
                        username:user.username
                    }, 'havhav', (err, token) => {
                        if (err) throw err
                        res.header('token', token) 
                        next()
                    })

                }
                else
                    res.status(403).send("unauthorized")
            })

    }

}
module.exports=vt;
```

Then in login page:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const middlecheck=require('./vt.js');
router.post('/login',middlecheck.vt,(req,res)=>{

    res.redirect(307,'/flights')
})
module.exports = router;
```

Then in "/flights/" route

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const middlecheck=require('./vt.js');
router.post("/",middlecheck.vt(req,res)=>{

    res.send("welcome to flights")
});
module.exports = router;
```

Then you can get it in the routes by using `req.accesstoken`

Comment: The issue is while passing from '/login' to '/flights' so your answer doesn't work for me ...

Comment: In route of flights you can get the value of token by req.accesstoken.

Comment: got undefined when try to print the value of it.